# Python function using Pandas datafram values as arguments

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Being not very experimented with python programming, I have to trigger a python function in my ETL

Goal: Run a RATE function on every row of a table containing financial data.

Here is the Function I have to use

```
import numpy as np 

 
Solution = np.rate(nper, pmt, pv, fv,when=1,guess=0.01,tol=1e-06, maxiter=100)
```

and as argument, I'd like to use data coming from a table stored in a Pandas DataFrame
In this case I presenting only one row for exemple purposes, but m table will most likely contains many rows

Table:

| nper | pmt | pv | fv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 281 | -22057 | 9365 |

Does anyone know how to structure the function?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.rate` uses array-like inputs, so you can simply pass the columns as arguments and will receive an array of rates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'nper': {0: 56}, 'pmt': {0: 281}, 'pv': {0: -22057}, 'fv': {0: 9365}})
np.rate(df.nper, df.pmt, df.pv, df.fv, when=1, guess=0.01, tol=1e-06, maxiter=100)
```

This uses the values `nper`, `pmt`, `pv`, `fv` of each row in the dataframe `df` in a vectorized manner. If `df` has`n` rows, the function will return an array of length `n` corresponding to the rate of each row.

To store the resulting rates in the dataframe `df`, you can assign in to a new column:

```
df['rate'] = np.rate(df.nper, df.pmt, df.pv, df.fv, when=1, guess=0.01, tol=1e-06, maxiter=100)
```

Note that `np.rate` is deprecated, so you should consider using the corresponding function in the numpy-financial library, https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial.

Comment: Thanks for replying @gofvonx . Would that still work in a case I have a table with multiples rows?

Comment: @Solide Let me know if that solves your problem and feel free to accept the answer if it does.

Comment: Thanks @gofvonx ! In the case you posted, the function is using dynamic values? or will it use whatever data is in the corresponding field?

Comment: @Solide It will use whatever data is contained in the dataframe `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do is creating a separate function for the rate rate function.
You can then use df.apply with axis 1, which will pass every row into this function. You can get the values out from each row and put it into your numpy.rate function.
Right now in the end you get a new column called Solution where you have what the rate function computed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "nper": [1,2,3],
    "pmt": [4,5,6],
    "pv": [7,8,9],
    "fv": [0,1,2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def RunRateFunction(row):
    x = np.rate(row.nper, row.pmt, row.pv, row.fv,when=1,guess=0.01,tol=1e-06, maxiter=100)
    return x

df["Solution"] = df.apply(RunRateFunction, axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
   nper  pmt  pv  fv  Solution
0     1    4   7   0 -1.000000
1     2    5   8   1       NaN
2     3    6   9   2 -1.348887
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)